Java serialization of classes with dependency injection with no framework
I am using dependency injection the following way, because it is not possible to use a framework yet:
class Dependency {
    public void do() {}
}

class Dependant {
    private final Dependency dependency;

    public Dependant() {
        this.dependency = new Dependency();
    }

    public Dependant(Dependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void do() {
        dependency.do()
    }
}

Now I want to serialize Dependant, but I don't want the Dependency to be serialized. The reason is that Dependency has no state. It could be all static methods but I use instance methods so that I can easyly  inject dependencies for testing. My mate tells me that serializing a class with no state makes no sense, so the code would remain like this:
class Dependant implements Serializable {
    private transient Dependency dependency;

    public Dependant() {
        this.dependency = new Dependency();
    }

    public Dependant(Dependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void do() {
        dependency.do()
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        in.defaultReadObject();
        this.dependency = new Dependency();
    }
}

Which has downsides:

I can't make the dependency final, as it must be inserted later.
I must add extra serialization code. This is not an issue for a single class but there are quite a lot of them and it would dirt the code.

I can use a "Transient" wrapper for the dependencies. The wrapper can be serialized and it would create the dependency on demand.
class Transient<T> implements Serializable {
    private final Supplier<T> supplier;
    private transient T dependency;

    public Transient(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public T get() {
        if (dependency == null) {
            dependency = supplier.get();
        }
        return dependency;
    }
}

class Dependant implements Serializable {
    private final Transient<Dependency> dependency;

    public Dependant() {
        this.dependency = new Transient(Dependency::new);
    }

    public Dependant(Transient<Dependency> dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void do() {
        dependency.get().do()
    }
}

However this makes the code a bit cumbersome, because a) in tests I must add the Transient that provides a mock (not so bad) and b) all the calls to the dependency must be wrapper.get().do().
My aim is to make serialization of classes faster.
Do you know a better solution?

It would be a lot easier just to serialize the singleton.  It's not hard and isn't going to have much overhead.
